# Spyder with Anaconda input() error message

Tags: python, spyder, anaconda3

I updated Anaconda recently and I use Spyder and when I tried to run a script, I have this error message. It seems to come from input() but I don't know how to fix it and I don't find solutions on Internet.

[image: Error message]

I don't understand, does anybody have an idea? what is the problem ?

I'm on Windows 10
Python 3.9

Comment: Which version are you on?  5.1.5 has had a lot of problems and Anaconda isn't putting the updates for it on the main channel.  They are only on conda-forge now.

Comment: Yes it's 5.1.5. I downloaded 5.3 Spyder version without Anaconda and it seems to work.
Thanks